# Regex get first name out of "Aardal, Prof.dr.ir. K.I. (Karen)"

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone help me write a regex to filter the name between parenthesis in a string like this: `Aardal, Prof.dr.ir. K.I. (Karen)`

I tried

```php
preg_match('~[^/]([^/])~', $fullname, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

But the return is

```
array
  0 => string 'Aa' (length=2)
  1 => string 'a' (length=1)
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. you can skip any character except the `(`
2. then match `(` and any character besides `)`
3. then match `)`
4. between `(` and `)` is now the capture-group "name"

Regex:

```
[^\(]*\((?<name>[^\)]+)\)
```

Tested with the tool [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). This regex matches two groups:

1. The whole string:  "Aardal, Prof.dr.ir. K.I. (Karen)"
2. The named group 'name': "Karen"

Notes:

- `(?<name>...)` is the named group
- To match the `(` etc. we have to escape it with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

Some standard string functions would do it too:

```
function extractName($subject)
{
    $openIndex = strpos($subject, '(');
    if ($openIndex !== false)
    {
        $closeIndex = strpos(substr($subject, $openIndex + 1), ')');
        if ($closeIndex !== false)
            return substr($subject, $openIndex + 1, $closeIndex);
    }
    else
        return '';
}

echo extractName('Aardal, Prof.dr.ir. K.I. (Karen)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following One

```
.*\((.*)\)
```

Then Capture First Group Value, Which will match following:

Aardal, Prof.dr.ir. K.I. (**Karen**)